# Powershell json RESTful api - Conditional Statement

Tags: json, powershell

Currently, I am attempting to write a conditional statement that states the following

```
If($JSON.response = false){
'Dont do anything and continue to the next block of code.'
}
```

Right now the JSON returns like this when there is no data:

```
 response_code response
 ------------- --------
             0 {}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
If($json.response = 0){
'Dont do anything here'
}elseif($json.response = 1){
'Do the code'
}
```

I'd like to add that response_code is always equal to 0 when the response is error free as in status code 200. However, when there are no fields returned response is just an empty hashtable.

Comment: You need to put `$` in front of false and also use `-eq` for comparisons like so: `If(JSON.response -eq $false){`

Comment: I gave it a shot, it's still continuing to my elseif condition, even though response is returning with nothing besides {}.

Comment: Do you really want to be testing `json.response` rather than `json.response_code`? The numeric comparison suggests that you should be testing `json.response_code`.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why are you saying json.response instead of $json.response ?  Isn't json a variable?

Comment: Hey Jeff, I thought that too and it works with a handful of other apis. But, in this case response_code only returns information on if the response is error free. Although I could be mistaken. Also Walter it was a syntax error on my part. I'll fix it once I'm back at my desk. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer since the object is an array it was best to roll out like this.

```
 If($json.object.Count -eq 0){
 'dont do the code'
 }Else{
 'Do the code'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to be testing `json.response` rather than `json.response_code`? The numeric comparison suggests that you should be testing `json.response_code`.

Also, if `json` is a structure that is stored in a variable, you should be testing it as `$json.response_code` - note the $ - and using the `-eq` comparison operator as @JamesC. noted.

Finally, unless you're likely in the future to change what you do in the event that `$json.response_code` is zero, just drop that test entirely, and only test for `$json.response_code` values where you actually do something.

Comment: Sounds like he will need to test both values response and resonse_code using `-and`. Might be useful to show what the if statement looks like since there is a couple of errors here to address.

Comment: @Matt: Good point, but the OP's code isn't really detailed enough to show context for using `$json.response`. The best I can do at the moment is to recast what he's got there; I'd simply write it

`if ($json.response_code = 1) {
# Do the code
}`

and omit the test where he does nothing entirely.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Hello, Jeff I appreciated the response. I do see your point and this would work with other RESTful apis. However, in this case response_code merely means http status 200. Which also means that even if there is no data on the item I am querying for, it will still return as "0".